# Hyperlink On x-axis

Tags: href

Please look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzXub/760/)
I am wanting to be able to click on home and about and for it to scroll to where the centre of where the href is located?

```
 <a name="index">home</a>
   <a name="about">about</a>
   <div><a href="about"></a></div>
   <div class="home"><a href="#index"></a></div>
```

but even this bit of code isn't working. Why?

I want a navigation panel with Home, About, Contact and Info Horizontally placed. And I want that to be perfectly in the centre. and to be fixed position.

I have managed to do this by

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.navigation').css({
        'right': $(this).scrollLeft()        
    });
});
```

But it is not perfectly in the centre I then want when you click on one of these it navigates you to the corresponding part of the page which is on a horizontal line with the other pages.

Comment: please update your question to clearly describe what you want to achieve...

Comment: i see you have update your question... but did you try it my way? without jquery?

Comment: may I ask why you think my updated bit of code isn't staying in the centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<a href="#index">home</a>
<a href="#about">about</a>
<a><div id="about"></div></a>
<a><div id="index" class="home"></div></a>
```

explanation: `href="#index"`   uses `#` and that indicates you use an id.
Put an id with the same name in de div.. and you go to that place

You dont even need the `<a>` tags in de div